# How do I remove any rows that are identical across all the columns except for one column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I merged 3 dataframes `mrna`, `meth`, and `cna`. I want to remove any duplicate rows that either have the same `Hugo_Symbol` column value or have the same values across all the remaining columns (i.e., columns starting with "TCGA-"). I also want to remove any rows that are identical across all the columns except for one column.

```
import re
import pandas as pd


dfs = [mrna, meth, cna]

common = pd.concat(dfs, join='inner')
common["Hugo_Symbol"] = [re.sub(r'\|.+', "", str(i)) for i in common["Hugo_Symbol"]]  # In Hugo_Symbol column, remove everything after the pipe except newline
tcga_cols = common.columns[1:]
mask = common.duplicated("Hugo_Symbol") | common.duplicated(tcga_cols)
common = common[~mask]
common
```

A snippet of the dataframe:

```
common_dict = common.iloc[1:10,1:10].to_dict()
common_dict

{'TCGA-02-0001-01': {1: -0.9099,
  2: -2.3351,
  3: 0.2216,
  4: 0.6798,
  5: -2.48,
  6: 0.7912,
  7: -1.4578,
  8: -3.8009,
  9: 3.4868},
 'TCGA-02-0003-01': {1: 0.0896,
  2: -1.17,
  3: 0.1255,
  4: 0.2374,
  5: -3.2629,
  6: 1.2846,
  7: -1.474,
  8: -2.9891,
  9: -0.1511},
 'TCGA-02-0007-01': {1: -5.6511,
  2: -2.8365,
  3: 2.0026,
  4: -0.6326,
  5: -1.3741,
  6: -3.437,
  7: -1.047,
  8: -4.185,
  9: 2.1816},
 'TCGA-02-0009-01': {1: 0.9795,
  2: -0.5464,
  3: 1.1115,
  4: -0.2128,
  5: -3.3461,
  6: 1.3576,
  7: -1.0782,
  8: -3.4734,
  9: -0.8985},
 'TCGA-02-0010-01': {1: -0.7122,
  2: 0.7651,
  3: 2.4691,
  4: 0.7222,
  5: -1.7822,
  6: -3.3403,
  7: -1.6397,
  8: 0.3424,
  9: 1.7337},
 'TCGA-02-0011-01': {1: -6.8649,
  2: -0.4178,
  3: 0.1858,
  4: -0.0863,
  5: -2.9486,
  6: -3.843,
  7: -0.9275,
  8: -5.0462,
  9: 0.9702},
 'TCGA-02-0014-01': {1: -1.9439,
  2: 0.3727,
  3: -0.5368,
  4: -0.1501,
  5: 0.8977,
  6: 0.5138,
  7: -1.688,
  8: 0.1778,
  9: 1.7975},
 'TCGA-02-0021-01': {1: -0.8761,
  2: -0.2532,
  3: 2.0574,
  4: -0.9708,
  5: -1.0883,
  6: -1.0698,
  7: -0.8684,
  8: -5.3854,
  9: 1.2353},
 'TCGA-02-0024-01': {1: 1.6237,
  2: -0.717,
  3: -0.4517,
  4: -0.5276,
  5: -2.3993,
  6: -4.3485,
  7: 0.0811,
  8: -2.5217,
  9: 0.1883}}
```

Now, I want to remove any rows that are identical across all the columns except for one column.

| Hugo_Symbol | TCGA-1 | TCGA-2 | TCGA-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 0.123 | 0.234 | 0.345 |
| Second | 0.123 | 0.234 | 0.478 |
| Third | 0.456 | 0.678 | 0.789 |
| Fourth | 0.789 | 0.456 | 0.321 |

In this example dataframe, the `First` and `Second` row have duplicate values in the all but one "TCGA-" column. This is the type of row that I want to remove.

Comment: can your provide a minimal reproducible example directly as dataframe? There is no Hugo_Symbol column in the provided dictionary

Comment: @mozway have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849444/15521392) we already solved a bit of the problem. now there is the "row almost duplicated" issue to solve. In my answer I also provided a little manipulated df of the original data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute the duplicates per column using `apply(pd.Series.duplicated)`, then count the True values per row and compare it to the wanted threshold:

```
ncols = df.shape[1]-1
ndups = df.drop(columns='Hugo_Symbol').apply(pd.Series.duplicated).sum(axis=1)
df2 = df[ndups.lt(ncols-1)]
```

output (using the simple provided example):

```
  Hugo_Symbol  TCGA-1  TCGA-2  TCGA-3
0       First   0.123   0.234   0.345
2       Third   0.456   0.678   0.789
3      Fourth   0.789   0.456   0.321
```

There is however one potential blind spot. Imagine this dataset:

```
A B C D
X X C D
A B X X
```

The first row won't be dropped as it comes first and has duplicates spread over several other rows (that might not be an issue in your case).

Comment: why is that a blind spot ? in that dataset no row should be dropped and won't.

Comment: It depends what you consider a duplicate, in my solution I consider it overall. For pairwise  duplicates you would need to compute all combinations.

Comment: the specification was delete the row where the value of all cols except max one is equal, and your code does that. in your blind spot example in each row 2 values differ

Comment: @Rabinzel I know what my code does (at least I hope :p), but from my experience of SO, I've often seen OPs change their mind and adding details afterwards ("*I forgot but I actually have this and that in my data and I rather want that*") so I prefer to warn ahead ;)

Comment: too generous of you :) I've seen enough to understand what you mean :D I think we just be at cross-purposes. I know "how dare I?!" but from my understanding and testing the code.... either i don't get the the warning or it just isn't necessary in that particular case